# Count every first occurrence in multiple ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, date, date-range, countif, find-occurrences

I have data spanning multiple years and I have all sorts of different `ifs` codes to find different bits of info based on the year the info falls in. But what I can't figure out is how to count each first occurrence within different years.
this string `=(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1)+0` will count only the very first occurrence, when I try to add other criteria so it counts the first occurrence between a date range it just doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Put an **S** on COUNTIF and make it COUNTIF**S**.

Comment: I know about adding the s, like I said I have all kinds of "ifs" strings... I have tried something like '=(COUNTIFS($Y:$Y,">="&$EC2,$Y:$Y,"<="&$ED2($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1)+0)' and '=IFS($Y:$Y,">="&EC2,$Y:$Y,"<="&ED2(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1)+0)' and all kinds of other variations of the syntax.

Comment: I thought you meant the newer IFS function; apparently @user902300 did too.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple criteria you need to use COUNTIFS (same like you use IFS)

## Sample Usage

```
COUNTIFS(A1:A10, ">20", B1:B10, "<30")

COUNTIFS(A7:A24, ">6", B7:B24, "<"&DATE(1969,7,20))

COUNTIFS(B8:B27, ">" & B12, C8:C27, "<" & C13, D8:D27, “<>10”)

COUNTIFS(C1:C100, "Yes")
```

## Syntax

```
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])

criteria_range1 - The range to check against criterion1.
criterion1 - The pattern or test to apply to criteria_range1.
criteria_range2, criterion2... - [ OPTIONAL ] - Additional ranges and criteria to check; repeatable.
```